# 自作フレームワークをimportすると「No such module 〜」のエラーが表示される

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, framework

現在以下のサイトを参考に自作のフレームワークを使おうとしているのですが、フレームワークをimportすると、importの行で「No such module 〜」のエラーが表示されてしまいます。
そのまでの手順は以下のサイトに書かれてある通りに行いました。

[[Xcode6] SwiftでCocoa Touch Frameworkを作る](http://mushikago.com/i/?p=5521)

どうすれば自作のフレームワークを使用できるようになるでしょうか？
どなたか解決できる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
以下のサイトを参考にFramework Search Pathsを設定したところ、「No such module〜」のエラーが消えてビルドできるようになりました。

[[ios][Xcode]framework search pathの指定](http://threetreeslight.com/post/76312863848/iosxcodeframework-search-path%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A)